# ¿Cuál es o era el significado literal de «acojonante»?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, españa

Las preguntas, primero: **¿es *acojonante* un término figurativo?** En cuyo caso, **¿cuál es o era originalmente su significado literal?** Doy por hecho que la respuesta a la primera pregunta es sí; mi sospecha es que *acojonante* ("que acobarda, que impresiona") tiene que ver con el conocido efecto del miedo extremo en los testículos. La pregunta apunta a si los hablantes actuales reconocen o adivinan esa relación.

La razón de la pregunta (si alguien interesa): estoy leyendo el *Ulysses* de Joyce en el original. Uno se encuentra con miles de palabras compuestas inusuales que son una pesadilla para el traductor porque el castellano no cuenta con las estructuras necesarias para expresarlas de manera sencilla. En el primer capítulo hay una famosa línea:

> — God! he said quietly. Isn't the sea what Algy calls it: a great
>   sweet mother? The snotgreen sea. The **scrotumtightening** sea. *Epi
>   oinopa ponton.* Ah, Dedalus, the Greeks! I must teach you. You must
>   read them in the original. *Thalatta! Thalatta!* She is our great
>   sweet mother. Come and look.

La palabra *scrotumtightening* es invención de Joyce; debería ser *scrotum-tightening* ("que tensa/ajusta el escroto") pero Joyce prescinde de guiones. En las traducciones uno se encuentra con espantosas literalidades como *"el mar tensaescrotos"*. Opino que *acojonante* funcionaría muy bien (aunque los lectores hispanoamericanos no lo comprendan) pero el efecto sólo funciona si en efecto la palabra preserva todavía un eco de significado literal (relacionado con el escroto o los testículos) por detrás del actual significado de "acobardante, apabullante".

Comment: Una expresión que denota el machismo de los abuelos: si los tienes eres valiente. si no los tienes ( _a == sin_ ) tienes miedo.

Comment: @enxaneta Sin embargo, en mayoría de los verbos que se forman con [*a* + sustantivo + *ar*], el prefijo a- no significa "sin" sino todo lo contrario. P.ej. _acariciar_ no significa "sin caricias".

Comment: Ja,ja @Rodrigo. Que gracioso! Seguramente que ya lo sabe que en este caso la *a* viene del latin *ad* = proximo, cercano. Yo me refería a la a *privativa* como de **abismo** = sin fondo, **acromo** = sin color, **átona** = sin tono, **anomalia** = que no es normal , **analfabeto** = que no sabe ni leer ni escribir . . .  etc

Comment: Pinta más bien como la *a-* de *acordonar* o *abultar*, que proviene del latín *ad-* y denota un cambio hacia una condición diferente que tiene que ver con la raíz sustantiva que se prefija. Mi pregunta iba a si los españoles que usan esta palabra la relacionan con un cambio de estado literal de los testículos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que la relación entre **acojonante** (en sus dos acepciones) y **cojón** se reconoce perfectamente, además de estar recogida en el DLE:

[**Acojonante**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0WN8YZ3):

> De *acojonar* y *-nte.*
>   1. adj. malson. Esp. Que acojona.

[**Acojonar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0WNLUYI):

> De *a*<sup>1</sup> y *cojón*.
>   1. tr. malson. Esp. acobardar. U. t. c. prnl.
>   2. tr. malson. Esp. Impresionar profundamente o dejar estupefacto.

Es muy conocido el texto, atribuido a Perez Reverte, sobre el uso de la palabra *cojón* y los diferentes significados según sus características y tamaño, número, compuestos con prefijos y sufijos, etc. Cito (extractado) de [este blog](http://carrilengua.blogspot.com/2011/12/morfologia-semantica-y-lexico-por.html):

> Un ejemplo de la riqueza del lenguaje castellano, es el número de acepciones de una simple palabra, como puede ser la muy conocida y frecuentemente utilizada, que hace referencia a los atributos masculinos, "cojones". Se trata de una palabra malsonante para algunos mientras que otros la tienen siempre en la boca.
>   Si va acompañado de un numeral, tiene distintos significados según el número utilizado. Así, "uno" significa caro o costoso (valía un cojón). "Dos", significa valentía (tenía dos cojones), "tres" significa desprecio (me importa tres cojones) y un número muy grande y par significa dificultad (lograrlo me costó mil pares de cojones).
>   ...
>   Los prefijos o sufijos modulan su significado:
>    **"a" expresa miedo (acojonado)**
>    "des" significa cansancio (descojonado)
>    "udo" indica perfección (cojonudo)
>    "azo" se refiere a la indolencia o abulia (cojonazos).
>   ...

Comment: Ese texto que atribuyen en ese blog a Perez Reverte es del año de catapún. Yo lo tengo en casa escrito a maquina de escribir en los años 70

Answer (score 1):

La perdida acepción de "cobarde" para *cojón* creo que aparece en estas entradas del Diccionario de la RAE:

> [**collón, na**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9oRXgGQ)
>
> Del it. *coglione*, y este del lat. vulg. *coleo, -ōnis* 'testículo'.
>
> 1. adj. coloq. cobarde (‖ pusilánime). U. t. c. s.
>
> **[acollonar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0WxcNTM)**
>
> De *collón*.
>
> 1. tr. coloq. acobardar. U. t. c. prnl.

Si bien *collón* proviene del italiano, ambas palabras , *collón* y *cojón*, derivan del latín usado para 'testículo'.

Es decir, respondiendo a tu pregunta, en español *cojón* no significó 'cobarde', pero en italiano sí. El asunto del sentido figurado habría que buscarlo en esa otra lengua.

Me queda entonces la duda de por qué los italianos relacionan los testículos con la cobardía. Aparentemente el italiano *coglione* deriva del francés *coion*, 'hombre flojo y sin energía'. De hecho, en el diccionario de 1789 de Esteban Terreros *collón* es definido como 'flojo, cobarde, que no sirve para cosa de substancia', lo que me deja la otra duda, de por qué los franceses relacionan los testículos con la flojera.